# Generate Gaussian data in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I need to generate a Gaussian vector,e.g. "delta" -with arbitrary size-, with zero mean and variance of "alpha".
If "alpha" is chosen such that norm(delta,2)<=0.5 with probability of e.g. 90%. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `var.*randn(1000,1) + mu` you can generate a vector with a certain variance `var` and mean `mu`. Then we calculate the `norm(delta,2)`. This operation is repeated `100000` times. In the variable `B` it is stored the values for which `norm(delta,2)<=0.5`. The probability is then `Prob=length(B)/length(Normv)`

```
mu = 0; alpha = 0.01537;
Normv=0;
REP=100000
for j=1:REP
    delta = alpha.*randn(1000,1) + mu;
    Normv(j)=norm(delta,2);
end
B=Normv(Normv<=0.5);
Prob=length(B)/length(Normv);
```

You could also include a for loop, sweeping the variance

```
Normv=0;
mu = 0; 
aux=1;
REP=10000;
variance = 0.014:0.0001:0.017;
for k=1:length(variance)
for j=1:REP
    delta = variance(k).*randn(1000,1) + mu;
    Normv(j)=norm(delta,2);
end
B=Normv(Normv<=0.5);
Prob(aux)=length(B)/length(Normv);
aux=aux+1;
end

plot(variance,Prob)
xlabel('Variance')
ylabel('Probability')
```

Here is the generated plot:

[Plot Probability(Variance)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDyON.png)

The `alpha` (variance) you are trying to find is 0.01537. The higher the `REP` the higher is the precision of your `alpha`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice answer. As you know, by norm(delta,2), we get data with Chi-square distribution. Can we generate data based on this view-with Chi-squared matlab functions?

Comment: Yes you could replace: "delta = alpha.*randn(1000,1) + mu;
    Normv(j)=norm(delta,2);" by chi2pdf(alpha,alpha). I am not aware of any function to do this. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks. A question, suppose in this piece of code we replace just : data=randn(1000,1);
for k=1:length(variance)
for j=1:REP
    delta = variance(k).*data + mu;     Normv(j)=norm(delta,2);
end                          %% why does not this give us a good figure?
I mean, generate random data before loops?!

Comment: Sorry but I didn´t understand what you want to replace. But did the code solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. The last question is just for knowledge. It is not obvious for me why in the case we create "random data" before "2 for loops" does not give the same "variance figure " as the case we create "random data" in "for loops"?

Comment: "delta" will contain 1000 points with random normal distribution. It means Normv will not be constant for a different  "delta" (because "delta" is random). But if we generate the "delta" vector 10000 times, we can then find norm(delta,2) for each one of them. And then find how many norm(delta,2) are below 0.5. The probability is then the ratio between this number and 10000. You can look: "Law of large numbers". Hope you can mark my answer as correct.

Comment: How about the case that the number of random points is about "10"?. I need the variance of these cases.